# input forcus only working on 1/2 fields in firefox & chrome (not in IE)

Tags: jquery, focus

The problem is that the focus function is only working on the "Name" (the first) and not on "Email" (the second). When it's focused it should change position of the background and thereby make a yellow border, which again works fine for the the first one.

Here is the js:

```
    $("#formLeft input").focus(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    });
    $("#formLeft input").blur(function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass("active");
    });
```

CSS

```
#formLeft {
width: 320px;
float: left;
}
#formLeft input {
    width: 250px;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    background: none;
    margin: 13px 0 0 13px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
#formLeft .input-bg {
    background: url(bilder/input-bg.jpg) top left no-repeat transparent;
    height: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
#formLeft div.active {
    background: url(bilder/input-bg.jpg) bottom left transparent;
    height: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="formLeft">

            <label for="Name">Name:</label>
            <div class="input-bg">
                <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" class="required" minlength="2" />
            </div>


          <label for="Email">Email:</label>
            <div class="input-bg">
                <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" class="required email" />
            </div>

        </div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the actual path to the input-bg.jpg? It would make testing easier.

Comment: If my answer solved the question for you, you should accept it as the answer.  If not, let me know and I'll help you figure out whats wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a jsfiddle with what you want in working order:

I added jquery onReady to make sure the elements exist before they get thier focus handlers bound.

http://jsfiddle.net/yxnFL/4/

I changed the images to colors, so that I could see whether or not its working properly.  My guess is that if you still have problems, it is an issue with your images.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i still can't make it work. In the 'live view' function inside dreamweaver it works and in IE as well, but not in firefox or chrome. How could it be a problem with my images if it works on 'name' in all browsers and on both in IE and dreamweaver?

Comment: Instead of setting the background to images, set it to a color and see if it still fails.  If it does, we need some more info in order to help you.  Did you add the onReady? The $(function() {  //yourstuff }); ?

Comment: Yes, I added the onReady. I also tested with colors and that fails to, so it's not the images. Is there any more code I should show?

Comment: Make sure you don't have more than one element with and id of formLeft .  Look at the source when your page is rendered and make sure that the markup looks right. Ctrl+Shift+C in Chrome will let you inspect elements. Also, make sure you don't have errors in your JS.  Describe the situation more in depth, is it just static, are you using ajax etc.?  Also, more code can't hurt.  Copy it exactly as you have it in your project.

Answer (score 1):

The focus function is working fine. Check this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/yxnFL/6/

I have used background colors for demo purpose.

It would be helpful if you can post the url of that "input-bg.jpg" image.